# Can we modify/remove global header section from Lightning Pages

Tags: lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I'm just curious in case we can modify or remove the global header section from a lightning app page.

Does anyone have any pointer for tweaking this section?

[image: Lightning Page Header]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution that seems a fit here is as follows:

Define a renderer for a custom component included in the Lightning page, and override the page rendering process by removing or making the specific class non-visible:

```
({
// Your renderer method overrides go here
afterRender: function (component, helper) {
    this.superAfterRender();
    // interact with the DOM here       

    //Full Header
    //document.getElementsByClassName('slds-grid--align-spread')[1].style.display='none';

    //Search Bar
    document.getElementsByClassName('slds-global-header__item--search')[1].style.display='none';
}    })
```

Please note that this workaround would work if Locker service is not enabled in your Org.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe so - as mentioned [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/global-header/)

> The functionality in the header is applicable across all contexts in the Salesforce ecosystem (internal or 3rd party).

Answer (score 3):

I'm a product manager at Salesforce working on this area.

I just updated our collection of Ideas. Scan the list for "header".

https://sfdc.co/xandersroadmap

Feel free to contribute there or get in touch with me. My email is listed there.

Thanks,
Xander

Comment: Hi Xander, welcome to SFSE! For the community - I know this is not a traditional answer for the platform, but I recommend voting to keep it in place because it is feedback from the relevant Salesforce PM.

Answer (score 1):

Please find another workaround for modifying ‘Global Header’  of lightning  pages:

1. Create an external CSS file with the following snippets: // This is
   to remove search box of the header // Add other required slds
   classes as required

   **.slds-global-header__item--search{
                   display: none; }**
2. Include this file as a Static resource in a custom lightning component of the page:

   `<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.Global_Search_Hide}" />`
3. Refresh your page

This solution should be working irrespective of Locker Service enablement in your Org.

Comment: You could have [updated](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/167107/edit) your answer; instead of adding a new one. This still seems a hack instead of correct solution.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma, yes that's correct, it's a work around.